# Can the Q create another universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

In VOY: [Death Wish](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)):

> He did this by taking Janeway to the Q Continuum, which was presented
> in the Human-comprehensible form of a house in the middle of a desert
> with a road running by it. **The road, he told her, represented the
> universe's edge and there was nothing left for him to explore.**

Would it have been possible for the Q to create a randomly generated universe with randomly generated aliens, and place Quinn inside to explore?

Comment: Personally I always interpreted the new era as the big bang.  Again strictly Personally I regard the Q continuum as a more foundational level of our reality such that our reality is kind of like a video game.  
QUINN: When I was a respected philosopher, I celebrated the continuity, the undeviation of Q life. I argued that our civilisation had achieved a purity that no other culture had ever approached. And it was wonderful, for a while. At the beginning of the New Era, life as a Q was a continuous dialogue of discovery and issues and humour from all over the universe. But look at them now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An existing question asked can Q destroy the universe, and while this question is not the same, it includes some of the supporting details for an answer:
[Could the Q destroy the universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215024/could-the-q-destroy-the-universe/215027)

> Yes, they could.

> As shown in various episodes, the Q have the power to create
> new dimensions, alter the very fabric of reality in any way they
> see fit and they can even hurt and kill themselves and each
> other and bring untold destruction on their own continuum.
>
> In Qpid (TNG S04E20), Q creates a temporary pocket
> dimension based on the story on Robin Hood, with the officers
> of the Enterprise playing Robin Hood and his Merry Men,
> much to the dismay of Worf. Q is able to create this dimension,
> give it an end time and even prevent himself from being able to
> interfere with it or know what's going to happen.

Because a pocket universe is still a universe, the answer is yes, Q can create a universe.

With their ability to create a universe established, the ability to introduce randomness of its generation and alien population can be surmised. Q powers increase the more act in unison; if one Q couldn’t do it, then X number of Q necessary for the particular plot likely could.

Comment: So then Quinn didn't have to die? At least not until he finished exploring.

Comment: Is a pocket dimension a whole universe?

Comment: I can see a case where it can be: rather than any commentary about the size or completeness of a pocket dimension itself, we know (or at least I have accepted) Q can destroy universes.So if Q destroyed the universe but for the pocket dimension, then the pocket dimension could be the whole universe; a case of less is more?

Comment: Could a Q create other Qs?  If so, each created Q could continuously create more Q's, increasing the population exponentially with no limits, and thus easily acquiring the necessary numbers to have the power to create as many universes as they felt like.

Comment: Hmm. Well in Voyager episode “The Q and the Grey,” Q implied that the Q never came into existence, but rather, always were. So maybe they already are and have bee in the exponentially-increased population that they ever will be?

Comment: I feel it should be pointed out that while the Q can kill each other, their battle (represented as a US civil war era battle) had consequences in the normal universe. They were causing massive destruction of stellar objects as a side effect. Leading me to believe that they in fact cannot create an actual universe, but only sequester or modify parts of the existing one.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman When the DeLancie Q wanted to have a child, he seemed to require a mate of some sort, either human or Q. It seems the Q reproduce sexually.

Comment: I just watched that particular episode, and I do not remember it being established that the Sherwood Forest recreation was created in any sort of pocket universe. For all we know, it was created in part of our own universe. I am, in fact, unaware of any canon indication that the Q can create universes, unless one counts the Q Continuum itself as a different universe.

Comment: @trlkly If a human mate will do, he has shown the ability to create humans from nothing, so he could easily create a suitable mate, or as many of them as he wants, spreading his seed Marvel's Ego-style.  Maybe it's a bit slower than just snapping them into existence, but over the grand scheme of things, it would still be possible to reproduce at an exponential rate.  The only logical conclusion for why they haven't already done so is that they simply don't want to.  Maybe they're just not cool with sharing power?

Answer (score 11):

Regardless of how it's described as the "universe", Quinn wanted to die because he had done everything that could possibly be done and was bored. I would assume this would include making as many new "universes" as he could for exploration. In other words, if it could be done, he's already done it.

That doesn't really address "Can Q's create universes" but could explain why Quinn still wanted to die, even with that power.

Comment: I didn't think about it, that's true.